# Wordpress outputting incorrect time for timezone

Tags: php, wordpress, date

I have a custom script in WordPress which is meant to fire an action at a specific time on a specific day - however it's firing too late (about 10 hours too late). I am in the GMT +10 Timezone so it makes sense that it is firing late due to it running on UTC. But why is it doing that?

I wrote a test script to see what is happening, NOTE: Within WP settings I have set the timezone to Brisbane Australia (GMT +10).

```
<?php
  echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s') . PHP_EOL;

  require_once('wp-load.php');
  
  echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s') . PHP_EOL;

  date_default_timezone_set('Australia/Brisbane');

  echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s') . PHP_EOL;
```

The output for this is:

```
2022-11-23 06:00:19 //[GMT +10]
2022-11-22 20:00:19 //[UTC]
2022-11-23 06:00:19 //[GMT +10]
```

Now the question is, why?

Interpreting the output compared to the code written; By default, the timezone is correct. When I include WP via `wp-load.php`, the timezone is reset to UTC, and then I have to force it back into the correct timezone via `date_default_timezone_set`.

Any ideas as to why WordPress is resetting the timezone back to UTC even though it is set correctly as Brisbane Australia within the CMS?

[image: Timezone within Wordpress is correct]

Comment: This is by design, WordPress intentionally lives in UTC. You can see this [here](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/5e32e7de29bb18b56298f4c7c08e1937421d9069/wp-settings.php#L66) and you can see that it is considered to be a critical failure for changing it [here](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/3596d1a534182173e0a723b8872290057918b825/wp-admin/includes/class-wp-site-health.php#L1129)

Comment: If you want to know the date/time inside of WordPress in the set timezone you can use `current_datetime` and `current_time`

Comment: @ChrisHaas I see, so I need to have the 'incorrect' timezone (UTC) on my server for wordpress to work as expected. Interesting, wonder why they just don't display a warning in the settings saying 'default system timezone is not UTC, changing the timezone on this page will not take effect'.

Comment: You can change WordPress’s timezone, and WordPress will use that for all WordPress functions. But WordPress also needs a base of sanity which is UTC, so it instructs PHP to stay in UTC, and when it has a need to it calculates the difference. If you use a non-WordPress function that is database, but interact with WordPress in an unofficial capacity, that’s the difference. If you can post a more specific gist of what you are doing we might be able to clear things up more.

Comment: "a non-WordPress function that is database" - "database" should have been "date-based"